# Is it possible to have dynamically named Navigation Properties in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

If I have a class with a collection, is it possible to make that ICollection generic and use Linq, so I can dynamically add tables?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Course
    {

        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can that ICollection be Generic, something akin to this?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
    {
        public class Course
        {

            public int CourseID { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public int Credits { get; set; }
            public TEntity T {get; set;}
            public ICollection<TEntity> T { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I have lots of tables that could be TEntity in a join table, and I would name it in the Linq query

Comment: And how would you expect to model that in the database?

Comment: I have a join table that has the table name.

Comment: But how could you dynamically add tables to your database? What you're asking doesn't make sense. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: My join table has table names in it.  There is a column named table_name and table_id.  The one-side joins to the join table and the join table can have x or more tables to join to.  It will not always have the same tables.  So I cannot have a collection for each table in my class.

Comment: Oh boy, that is awful. You've effectively made a database inside a database, but in doing so you've removed referential integrity. No, EF won't support that, and I don't think you'll find any ORM that will.

Comment: When you don't know all the tables that someone might be connected to, I guess I could do a lot of left joins.